# Why isn't the genus of a Mobius strip larger than $1$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

So I understand that one can create a closed loop (inside/on) a mobius strip. And cutting if we cut along the loop what remains will still be a connected surface.

Meaning that the genus is $\geq 1$. However I don't understand what stops us from drawing another loop. Following this around the loop we get that it does not intersect our previous loop, or itself. And if we cut along this loop, we again get a connected surface. So I can't see why the genus of a mobius strip is 1.

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29  It says the genus is defined for closed surfaces, what the möbius band is not?!

Comment: The Mobius band is closed. (Unless you consider the open Mobius strip, which I am not.) Anyway, the issue has been resolved now.

Comment: I thought "closed" meant compact without boundary...

Answer (score 1):

The connected surface that results from cutting along a loop on a Mobius strip is homeomorphic to a cylinder. But cutting along a loop on a cylinder will always produce a disconnected space (either a disk and a cylinder minus a disk, or two cylinders).

Comment: Because of the two twists? Okay. But I am still not seeing where my argument is failing. (But of course it is somewhere!)

Comment: sorry. confusion over! of course the extra cutting is disconnected.